# Illegal value in dgssvx when using Armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

I'm actually using the Armadillo library to solve sparse linear system in my c++ code.

When I want to use the spsolve() function, which call SuperLu, I get this error :

** On entry to dgssvx parameter number 13 had an illegal value

When I don't use spsolve() and work with dense matrices, every thing is going well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: provide the code to reproduce error.

Answer (score 0):

When I look into the dgssvx routine, the error 13 is relative to bad format of the right hand side b.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std; 
using namespace arma;

int main() {

sp_mat A = sprandu<sp_mat>(1000,1000,0.1) ;
vec b = randu<vec>(1000) ;
vec x =spsolve(A,b) ;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exact code (same include) runs for me using  GCC version 6.3.0 and Armadillo version 7.600.2. Are you linking to the SuperLU library properly in your program? Is ARMA_USE_SUPERLU defined? It must be something to do with the linking since `dgssvx` is a wrapper for the superlu library call: [`dsgvx.c`](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~xiaoye/SuperLU/superlu_code_html/dgssvx_8c.html), [`def_superlu.hpp`](https://git.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/jhadida/drayn/blob/9740300278bae38d74d0ffc4580cb0bf156fbcbc/src/arma/armadillo_bits/def_superlu.hpp).

It sounds like when you call `spsolve` Armadillo is not able to call SuperLU. Not sure if the order matters but I link SuperLU then LAPack then BLAS.